# AngularJS : UI-Grid changing sub grid as per parent grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

in my case if a column is moved or pinned same changes should reflect in sub grid also.I have written a function for this which changes the properties in subgrid as per parent but not able to find any event which occurs on pinning of columns on parent grid so that i can call my function.currently i am using this event

$scope.gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered($scope,$scope.pinSubGridColumns)

but its fired too many times and the view is getting distorted.Also if i pin columns in parent grid then sub grid columns starts after these columns but i want subgrid columns aligned as per parent so if i have id column in parent grid then subgrid id column should be below it even if it is pinned.how can i achieve this?

here is the demo on plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/AKUFxTaJ2c3fLvl7AZin?p=preview

function :

```
$scope.pinSubGridColumns=function()
{
  for(i=0;i<$scope.gridApi.grid.columns.length;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<$scope.subGridColumnDefs.length;j++)
    {
      if($scope.gridApi.grid.columns[i].name===$scope.subGridColumnDefs[j].name)
  {
      if($scope.gridApi.grid.columns[i].renderContainer==="left")
      {

       $scope.subGridColumnDefs[j].pinnedLeft=true;
       $scope.subGridColumnDefs[j].pinnedRight=false;
      }
      else if($scope.gridApi.grid.columns[i].renderContainer==="right")
      {
        $scope.subGridColumnDefs[j].pinnedLeft=false;
        $scope.subGridColumnDefs[j].pinnedRight=true;
     }
     else
     {
        $scope.subGridColumnDefs[j].pinnedLeft=false;
        $scope.subGridColumnDefs[j].pinnedRight=false;
     }

   }
  }
 }
 if( $scope.subGridApi!==undefined)
 {
    $scope.subGridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
 }

}
```